# Malloc and Segfault

Tags: segmentation-fault, malloc

I've just started looking into how memory management on an x86_64 system works, so I'm really new at this stuff. If I allocate some memory using malloc, and then continuously increment the pointer in a while loop, and check the value there, it eventually segfaults a few thousand addresses later. What I don't understand is why it doesn't segfault the FIRST time I go beyond the size I malloced. Why is it thousands of accesses later that it eventually segfaults? Thanks guys

Comment: Undefined behaviour. It is, by definition, not defined to do anything in particular.

Comment: A call to malloc may result in a larger unit of virtual memory being mapped into your process's address space than the size you requested.  So writing past the end of the requested memory may not result in a segfault.  One possible outcome of "undefined behavior" is  "it works anyway".

Comment: So its really as simple as just being undefined behavior, or does it have something to do with the page table?